# Как сделать выборку из двух таблиц MySQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, структуры

Ситуация такова. У меня в bd есть две таблицы.
1) users (id, login, pass...)
2) files (id, name, id_user, id_user_check...)

Проблема такова: В таблице files два поля ссылаются на id users. как мне их вывести?

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT * FROM `files` LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=files.id_user LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=files.id_user_check
```

или как правильно решить эту задачу или перестроить таблицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос - сделайте так

```
SELECT <перечислите поля> 
FROM `files` 
   LEFT JOIN users u1 ON u1.id=files.id_user 
   LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id=files.id_user_check
```